# Codeigniter 4: how do I get a series of the next and previous rows using the builder class or even with a regular query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-4

This is my current query which retrieves an item according to a parameter in the URL($qs):
I would like to get 2 or 3 of the previous and next rows of the item.

```
    public function show_questions($qs = false)
     {
      $db = \Config\Database::connect();
      $builder->select('*');
      $builder->where('question_id ='. $qs);
      $builder->join('segments_en', 'questions_en.tape = segments_en.tape');                
      $query = $builder->get();
      return $query->getResultArray();                  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I separated **table name**(*movie*), **id column name** (*Movie_ID*) and **Limit**(*2*) to variables, because I used a sample tables (with movies to testing)
I attached the result

```
public function show_questions($qs = false)
{
    $sql = array();
    $table = "questions_en";
    $joined_table = "segments_en";
    $id_key = "question_id";
    $limit = 2;

    $db = \Config\Database::connect();
    $builder = $db->table($table);

    // Select previous records
    $builder->select('*');
    $builder->join($table, $table.'.tape = '.$joined_table.'.tape');
    $builder->where($id_key.' >'. $qs);
    $builder->orderBy($id_key, 'ASC');
    $builder->limit($limit);
    $sql[] = '('. $builder->getCompiledSelect() .')';


    // Select record which is identified by ID ($qs)
    $builder->select('*');
    $builder->join($table, $table.'.tape = '.$joined_table.'.tape');
    $builder->where($id_key, $qs);
    $sql[] = '('. $builder->getCompiledSelect() .')';

    // Select next records
    $builder->select('*');
    $builder->join($table, $table.'.tape = '.$joined_table.'.tape');
    $builder->where($id_key.' <'. $qs);
    $builder->orderBy($id_key, 'DESC');
    $builder->limit($limit);
    $sql[] = '('. $builder->getCompiledSelect() .')';

    $sql_query = implode('
UNION
', $sql);

    $query_string = "SELECT * FROM ($sql_query) questions ORDER BY ".$id_key." ASC";

    $query = $db->query($query_string);
    //var_dump($query->getResultArray());
    return $query->getResultArray();
}
```

[image: query result sample]

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to try this tomorrow, but just so i understand - you are taking a query for previous and another for next and then unioning them into third query and returning the result? And the initial result would be the middle one-in this case-3.